# How to POST to a custom endpoint with Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I need to submit a POST request to a custom endpoint in my Ember.js app. The request is to submit a user's email to reset password:

```
POST http://example.com/api/v1/users/password
Data: { user: { email: 'hello@example.com' } }
```

Essentially we are creating a new password because we are submitting a POST request. But the endpoint and the namespace don't match up. I think it would make sense to create some sort of custom method on the User model which submits the email. How can I submit a POST request to this endpoint, namespacing the data under `user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do something like:

```
resetPassword(){
  const data = {user:{email: this.get('email')}};
  const adapter = this.store.adapterFor('user');
  const baseUrl = adapter.urlForFindAll('user');
  return Ember.$.post(`${baseUrl}/password`, data);
}
```

ember-data doesn't really touch custom endpoints like that (I wish it did though).

Comment: Yeah, custom adapter is the way. http://cball.me/non-restful-api-calls-with-ember-data/